# How to draw points in 3D and provide labels for each?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, labeling

Is is possible to draw something like this in Mathematica?

[image]

Comment: Certainly. Look at `Text` in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
co = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}};

Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[co], Black, 
  Style[MapThread[Text, {{"a", "b", "c"}, co - 0.1}], Bold, 16]}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want flat 2-d markers rendering 3D data, symbols for markers tends to be pretty handy (and has a long history).

Simple example:

```
targetPoints[
  data_] := {Style[Map[Text["\[CirclePlus]", #] &, data], Blue, 14], 
  Style[MapIndexed[Text[#2[[1]], #] &, # - {1., 1., -1.} & /@ data], 
   12]}

cdPoints[data_] := {Style[Map[Text["\[CircleDot]", #] &, data], Red, 
   14], Style[
   MapIndexed[Text[#2[[1]], #] &, # - {1., 1., -1.} & /@ data], 12]}

sqPoints[data_] := {Style[Map[Text["\[Square]", #] &, data], 
   RGBColor[0.31, 0.5, 0.4], Bold, Large], 
  Style[MapIndexed[Text[#2[[1]], #] &, # - {1., 1., -1.} & /@ data], 
   12]}

Graphics3D[{sqPoints[RandomReal[{10, 55}, {8, 3}]], 
   cdPoints[RandomReal[{10, 55}, {8, 3}]],
   targetPoints[RandomReal[{10, 55}, {7, 3}]]} // Flatten, 
 Axes -> True]
```

yields:

[image: 3dBoxed]

or if you really don't like the box, and enjoy that sort of flat aspect, can play with `Graphics3D` [options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html)

```
Graphics3D[{sqPoints[RandomReal[{10, 55}, {8, 3}]], 
   cdPoints[RandomReal[{10, 55}, {8, 3}]],
   targetPoints[RandomReal[{10, 55}, {7, 3}]]} // Flatten, 
 Axes -> True, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {{10, 60}, {10, 60}, {10, 60}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: noBox]